# ConTeXt: Combining footnotes with margin texts

Tags: footnotes, context

**Background**

In my document I use modified footnotes that are defined like this:

```
\def\mya#1{%
  \tfx\high{a#1}%
}

\definenote[aNote]
  [before={\blank[4mm]},
   after={\blank[-8mm]},
   textcommand=\mya,
   paragraph=yes,
   rule=off]

\setupnotation[aNote]
  [alternative=serried,
   before={a},
   numbercommand=\tf,
   style={\switchtobodyfont[8.5pt]},
   way=bysection,
   width=broad]
```

which results in a block of footnotes without a footnote mark in the margin of the page.

---

**Problem:**

I would like to combine the footnote mechanism of ConTeXt with the possibility to annotate the footnotes via margin texts. Unfortunately, my attempts to implement this, for instance with

```
\aNote{This is my text.\inmargin{And this is an annotation.}}
```

or

```
\aNote{This is my text.\margindata[inouter]{And this is an annotation.}}
```

don't yield any result. The footnote is displayed, but not the margin text. I assume this has something to do with the footnote mark (maybe the space in the footer's margin is reserved for footnote marks only?).

Another approach I have tried is to put a footnote inside a footnote, like so:

```
\def\mya#1{%
  \tfx\high{a#1}%
}

\definenote[aNote]
  [before={\blank[4mm]},
   after={\blank[-8mm]},
   textcommand=\mya,
   paragraph=yes,
   rule=off]

 \setupnotation[aNote]
  [alternative=serried,
   before={a},
   numbercommand=\tf,
   style={\switchtobodyfont[8.5pt]},
   way=bysection,
   width=broad]

\definenote[marginNote]

\setupnote[marginNote][location=none]
\setupnotation[marginNote][
    align={flushleft,bottom},
    location=bottom,
    width=broad,
    numbercommand=\gobbleoneargument
]
\setuptexttexts[margin][]
    [{\framed[%
    align={right,bottom},
    frame=off,
    width=\rightmarginwidth
    ]{\placenotes[marginNote]}}]
\starttext
This is my main text.\aNote{Footnote text.\marginNote{Something additional.}}
\stoptext
```

which is close to what I want to achieve, but the text in `\marginNote` should be displayed in the same line as the footnote it refers to.

---

**Question:**

Is there a way to combine these two mechanisms so that I get an annotated footnote? Or can my "footnote inside a footnote" example be altered in a way so that the second note it is in the same line as the first footnote?

---

**Minimal working example**

```
\def\mya#1{%
  \tfx\high{a#1}%
}

\definenote[aNote]
  [before={\blank[4mm]},
   after={\blank[-8mm]},
   textcommand=\mya,
   paragraph=yes,
   rule=off]

\setupnotation[aNote]
  [alternative=serried,
   before={a},
   numbercommand= {\tf},
   style={\switchtobodyfont[8.5pt]},
   way=bysection, 
   width=broad]

\starttext
Main text.\aNote{Footnote.\margindata[inouter]{Addenda.}}
\stoptext
```

Comment: This seems like a very involved problem.  It might be better to ask this on the mailing list.

Comment: Thanks for the notion! In case the community has a solution I'll post it here.